# Can i trigger a ripple effect on another event except onClick?

Tags: android, triggers, effect, ripple

I have a timer, and i want to trigger a ripple effect every second.
I don't have a problem with the ripple effect, i can't find a way to trigger it on another event except the user's onClick.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to acheive something like this? 
https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background